# Which is faster (time complexity) in groovy, .find() or .each()?

Tags: groovy, find, each

So I'm making a research on which method in groovy makes faster result.

Let's say we have:
`def storage = [{item:"apple", amount:3, color: "red"}, {item:"mango", amount:5, color: "yellow"}]`

Is doing this:

```
def someMap = [:]
storage.each {
   someMap[it.item] = [amount: it.amount, color: it.color]
}
```

So when we need to get the amount of an item, we do this:
`someMap["apple"].amount`

Better than doing this? :

```
def storageFindByItem = { itemName ->
  return storage.find{
    i -> i.item == itemName
  }
}
```

So when we need to get the amount of an item, we do this:
`storageFindByItem("apple").amount`

Comment: Clearly the first option is better as far as time complexity goes (and you can improve it by using a hash map instead). But it costs you some extra memory.

Comment: Hi, can you provide an example on how I can be able to improve the 1st option? @ernest_k

Comment: I mean use `def someMap = new HashMap<...>()` instead of `def someMap = [:]`

Comment: Alright! If possible, can you give me a quick answer on why hashmap is better? If it's okay with you.

Comment: "Is A better than B" needs a metric. Then measure for that metric.  Assuming you want raw speed, you are best served using a profiler, measure the outcome. In general building a lookup you will use alot will be more efficient. But if your real problem is as "small" as the example you are using, a few linear searches just don't matter. Also for golfing `def storageByItem = storage.collectEntries(new HashMap()) { [it.item, it] }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that when it comes to performance assessments, you should [perform your tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java) and decide from the results.

With that said, the first option searches an indexed map and would be presumably faster. But this is probably more likely when you're using a `HashMap` for `someMap` rather than `[:]` (`LinkedHashMap`). And of course this would take an additional amount of memory.

The second option will always be searching linearly whereas finding in a hash map runs in constant time.

All this could be speculation in the face of actual test results, which would really be encouraged.